# I can't unshelve changes from one branch to another

Tags: tfs, unshelve

I'm using tfpt tool for moving a shelveset from one branch to another. I've read some stackoverflow questions about it but neither seems to fit to my problem. I'm running the command like this:

```
tfpt unshelve "my shelveset name" /migrate /source:source_brach /target:target_branch
```

When I'm doing this I'm getting an error like this example:

> The change to filen_name_with_path cannot be unshelved because the
>   server path is not mapped in the local workspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your workspace mapping includes both branches.  Do a get latest on both branches first to test this is setup right.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that

1. One or more of your workspace mappings include both branches (they do not have to be in the same workspace);
2. The location from where you launch the command is in your *target* workspace.

Comment: Number 2 did it for me. I had to type the "cd" command to navigate to the target folder then I ran the command from there.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go to your target branch mapped local folder using cmd and run the command from there. It should work